# Send email automatically every day in App maker

Tags: google-app-maker

I need to send an email alert everyday to notify pending Approvals to all approvers. Does this possible in App maker? Please suggest.

I am sending approval emails immediately after request created and this is working absolutely fine.

I want to know the event or an utility in App Maker which can help to trigger emails for pending approvals to approvers every day.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Triggers in App Makers server script.
Please check the sample code below for more details.

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("functionName").timeBased().everyDays(1).create();
```

You have to create a function which sends the email and add the name of the function in the place of newTrigger("functionName") with the quotes.

Comment: Thanks Akhil, That helped.